# How to add 'hidden' items in a TComboBox?

Tags: delphi

I have a TCombobox in which I show some items to the user. But the text for the items that I show to the user are different than the text that I need.

For example the combobox *Items* and the text that I actually need is:

```
Entry start    ->  cmd_estart
Entry End      ->  cmd_eend
```

The 'command' that I need when the users clicks the first item is 'cmd_estart'. There is a way to put a second list of items into the combobox?

In other words I need another list of Items, in 'parallel' with the original list of list of Items that already exists.

I hope there is something like this already made :) So, if you know a control like this, please post a link.

---

Note: This is not a duplicate of [How to create a combobox with two columns (one hidden) in Delphi 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006577/how-to-create-a-combobox-with-two-columns-one-hidden-in-delphi-7?) because that question asks about how to show two columns in a combobox. AND the solutions provided there are not as good as the one provided here (by TLama).

Comment: Just keep a TStringList somewhere and use the combobox itemindex as index?

Comment: Or create a "command" object and assign it to the Objects[Index] property of the combobox?

Comment: @whosrdaddy-I think I like the second idea

Comment: I think I have found it: http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/items_addobject.htm

Comment: Please check the following post :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006577/how-to-create-a-combobox-with-two-columns-in-delphi-7

Comment: Why not just make a record containing fields: Index, Caption, Action. where Index is the position of the item in the array AND combobox. Caption is the displayed text and Action is the text you actually need. Once submitted get index X from the array where X is the active index of your combobox.

Comment: @TeunPronk-How you 'connect' all this to a graphic interface?

Comment: *"because that question asks about how to show two columns in a combobox"* - That's because that question asks about the wrong solution to the identical problem of yours, but the answer doesn't follow, it provides a solution to the actual problem. Read the question and the answer there.

Comment: .. very much like the answer here doesn't follow. How does your answer address adding hidden items?

Comment: No, that question asks about displaying one column and hiding a second piece of associated information, which is exactly what your question is asking. Don't just read the title of the linked question - read the **content** of the question, as well as the answers posted, which is precisely what I did before closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz-run the exaple I provided and you will see that for the 'User nice text##usr_bkg_text' string, the combo will show only the first half of the string while with the ComboChange you get the second half. So, my answer works. If you don't understand my code, I can provide additional explanations.

Comment: @Altar - I read the code. It doesn't add hidden items or it doesn't put a second list of items to a combo box. It keeps a separate list in a descendant.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz- It this achieves what I want to do. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Altar - That was my point. The linked question asks a different question too, but the answer there solves the problem. Like it solves the problem asked here...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - Yes and no. Yes = that answer solves the general problem. No = TLama's answer solves my particular problem. Just because TLama provides a very different approach (that solves better my problem) shows that the questions are somehow different. As TLama shows, my solution involves creating an unnecessary object. Ken's solution creates even more unnecessary objects (actually one per entry). I know, few extra objects is not the end of the world (unless you are running on a small laptop with Win7 and 1GB ram :) ). Let's acknowledge that Tlama's answer is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution. It won't work if you need to sort the list (I don't). **The solution provided by TLama is better.** Please vote up his answer.

```
TYPE
  TDualComboBox = class(TComboBox)
   private
    FDItems: TStrings;      { Strings are separated with ##}
    function getDItems: TStrings;
    procedure setDItems  (const DualItems: TStrings);
   protected
   public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AddDualItem(const DualItem: String);
    function  SelectedDualItem: string;
    property  DualItems: TStrings read getDItems write setDItems; { Strings are separated with ##}
   published
   end;

procedure Register;

IMPLEMENTATION

Constructor TDualComboBox.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
 inherited Create(AOwner);
 FDItems:= TStringList.Create;
end;


destructor TDualComboBox.Destroy;
begin
 FreeAndNil(FDItems);
 inherited;
end;



procedure TDualComboBox.AddDualItem(CONST DualItem: String);
VAR
   sField, sValue: string;
begin
 SplitString(DualItem, '##', sField, sValue);
 Items  .Add(sField);
 FDItems.Add(sValue);
end;


function TDualComboBox.SelectedDualItem: string;
begin
 if ItemIndex < 0
 then Result:= ''
 else Result:= FDItems[ItemIndex];
end;
```

---

And this is the test program:

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Box:= TcComboBox.Create(Self);
 Box.Parent:= Self;
 Box.Top := 200;
 Box.Left:= 200;
 Box.OnChange:= ComboChange;

 Button1Click(Sender);
end;


procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Box.AddDualItem('User nice text##usr_bkg_text');
end;


procedure TForm5.ComboChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 lblInfo.Caption:= Box.SelectedDualItem;
end;
```

Comment: String lists have for your task name value pairs, so there's no need to have a separate string list for that. You can display value and get name (having items like `cmd_estart=Entry start`).

Comment: That's where you use owner drawing. You set the `Style` e.g. to `csOwnerDrawFixed` and in the `OnDrawItem` event handler you print out the value of the item. Something [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/8A4e4JKb).

Comment: The name value pairs are parsed by the first occurence of the `NameValueSeparator` char that you can change if you want. By default it's the `=` char so the command name (the name portion) must not contain this char. The value portion can.

Comment: I use now | as separator. = is too often used.

Comment: @TLama-Too bad some moderator hurried to close the question. Your answer was very good :(

Comment: This solution won't work if the combobox gets sorted, because the indexes between your two lists will get out of sequence.

Comment: @KenWhite-I don't need to sort the list. That was not in the Requirements.

Comment: @TLama-
 
Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? :)